# C struct quick sort for strings

Tags: c, struct, malloc, quicksort

I have problem with quick sort. It should sort books with author's names. Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct book {
    char title[80];
    char autor[80];
    int pages;
};

int comparator (const void * a, const void *b)
{
    struct book * ia=(struct book*)a;
    struct book * ib=(struct book*)b;
    return (strcmp(ia->autor,ib->autor));
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int c = 2;
    int i;

    //Pointer to array of struct pointers, malloc for 2 structs
    struct book **ptr = (struct book*)malloc(c*sizeof(struct book));
    for(i=0;i<c;i++) {
            //malloc for every struct
            //also, if I'm doing it right?
            ptr[i] = (struct book*)malloc(sizeof(struct book));
            printf("Title: ");
            scanf("%s",ptr[i]->title);
            printf("Autor: ");
            scanf("%s",ptr[i]->autor);
    }
    for(i=0;i<c;i++) {
            printf("Before Quick sort Autor: %s, Title: %s \n",ptr[i]->autor,ptr[i]->title);
      }
    qsort(ptr,2, sizeof(struct book), comparator);
          printf("QSORT DONe...\n\n");
      for(i=0;i<c;i++) {
            printf("TEST");
            printf("After quick sort: Autor: %s, Title: %s \n",ptr[i]->autor,ptr[i]->title);
      }

    return 0;
}
```

So program compiles but it reaches only to `printf("TEST");` (TEST prints on screen) and then it crashes. 
Did I destroy my array with that quick sort? Or what could happen?

Also could you check my code if it's ok? Especially what `mallocs` (really) do in my code, because I'm not sure if I used them properly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were some small issues and confusions:

1) You were missing `#include <string.h>` for `strcmp`

2) You were allocating an array of pointers, which is probably not what you meant to do. An array in C is a pointer to the first element of the array, therefore if you allocate using `(struct book*) malloc(n * sizeof(struct book))` you're already allocating a full array of `n` books.
You could also allocate an array of pointers to books, in which case you'd need to assign each pointer to a newly allocated book.

So you could do either of the following (and your code is mixing both):

`struct book** ptr = (struct book**) malloc(c * sizeof(struct book*));`

`struct book* ptr = (struct book*) malloc(c * sizeof(struct book));`

In the first case, you need to allocate new books (and therefore the `malloc` inside the loop would make sense)

In the second case, you just use the array directly, which is what I changed the following code to do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct book {
  char title[80];
  char autor[80];
  int pages;
};

int comparator(const void * a, const void *b)
{
  struct book * ia = (struct book*)a;
  struct book * ib = (struct book*)b;
  return (strcmp(ia->autor, ib->autor));
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  int c = 3;
  int i;

  //Pointer to array of struct pointers, malloc for 2 structs
  struct book* ptr = (struct book*) malloc(c*sizeof(struct book));

  if (ptr == NULL) {
    printf("Could not allocate data\n");
    return 1;
  }

  for (i = 0;i<c;i++) {
    printf("Title: ");
    scanf("%s", ptr[i].title);
    printf("Autor: ");
    scanf("%s", ptr[i].autor);
  }
  for (i = 0;i < c;i++) {
    printf("Before Quick sort Autor: %s, Title : %s \n", ptr[i].autor, ptr[i].title);
  }
  qsort(ptr, c, sizeof(struct book), comparator);
  printf("QSORT Done...\n\n");
  for (i = 0;i<c;i++) {
    printf("TEST");
    printf("After quick sort: Autor: %s, Title: %s \n", ptr[i].autor, ptr[i].title);
  }

  free(ptr);

  return 0;
}
```

3) Finally, it is a good practice to test the result of your `malloc` and to call `free` when you don't need it anymore.

Answer (score 2):

It is shown for the point to be changed(for *Pointer to array of struct pointers*(but double pointer is not necessary)) following as

1. `#include <string.h>`
2. `struct book * ia=*(struct book**)a;
   struct book * ib=*(struct book**)b;`
3. `struct book **ptr = malloc(c*sizeof(struct book*));`
4. `qsort(ptr,2, sizeof(struct book*), comparator);`

---

Perhaps version what you want

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct book {
    char title[80];
    char autor[80];
    int pages;
};
int comparator (const void * a, const void *b)
{
    struct book * ia=(struct book*)a;
    struct book * ib=(struct book*)b;
    return (strcmp(ia->autor,ib->autor));
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int c = 2;
    int i;

    struct book *ptr = malloc(c*sizeof(struct book));
    for(i=0;i<c;i++) {
            printf("Title: ");
            scanf("%s",ptr[i].title);
            printf("Autor: ");
            scanf("%s",ptr[i].autor);
    }
    for(i=0;i<c;i++) {
            printf("Before Quick sort Autor: %s, Title: %s \n",ptr[i].autor,ptr[i].title);
    }
    qsort(ptr,2, sizeof(struct book), comparator);
          printf("QSORT DONe...\n\n");
    for(i=0;i<c;i++) {
            printf("TEST");
            printf("After quick sort: Autor: %s, Title: %s \n",ptr[i].autor,ptr[i].title);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Karmel change as _Pointer to array of struct pointers_. You have confused with Pointer to array of structs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to give you an answer which will keep the definition of ptr, which is a pointer to a pointer to `struct book`, and also change a minimal amount of your code. This means we will allocate an array of pointers to `struct book`, and then for each pointer in that array we will allocate an actual object `struct book`.

The first malloc will allocate an array of `c`pointers to `struct book`:

```
struct book **ptr = (struct book**)malloc(c*sizeof(struct book*));
```

The for loop which allocates an object `struct book` using malloc is then correct.

The second correction is at the qsort() call. We are sorting pointers to `struct book`, not actual objects `struct book`.

```
qsort(ptr,4, sizeof(struct book*), comparator);
```

Then the comparison function needs a fix. Since we are sorting pointers, the comparison function will return a pointer to a pointer to `struct book`. So we need to dereference that pointer to our pointer to `struct book`:

```
int comparator (const void * a, const void *b)
{
    struct book* ia=*(struct book**)a;
    struct book* ib=*(struct book**)b;
    return (strcmp(ia->autor,ib->autor));
}
```